# mysql innoDB Performance

Tags: mysql, debian, innodb, xen

I have some trouble with my mySQL innoDB Engine..
SQL Statements like "select * from posts" takes a long time.
This is my MySQL Config:

```
[mysql]

# CLIENT #
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /var/lib/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
#default_storage_engine         = InnoDB
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql

bind-address            = 127.0.0.1

# MyISAM #
key_buffer_size                = 32M
myisam_recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max_allowed_packet             = 16M
max_connect_errors             = 1000000

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING #
log_bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire_logs_days               = 14
sync_binlog                    = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp_table_size                 = 64M
max_heap_table_size            = 64M
query_cache_type               = 0
query_cache_size               = 0
max_connections                = 500
thread_cache_size              = 50
open_files_limit               = 65535
table_definition_cache         = 1024
table_open_cache               = 2048
read_rnd_buffer_size           = 1M
query_cache_type               = 1

# INNODB #
innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group      = 2
innodb_log_file_size           = 256M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_file_per_table          = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 4G

# LOGGING #
log_error                      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes  = 1
slow_query_log                 = 1
slow_query_log_file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

While a sql statement is running i got an load avg ~2.0
the assigned cores are mostly 0.0 % usage..

iostat tell me:

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.39    0.00    0.26    5.15    0.04   94.16

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
xvdap2          152.80       139.39      5550.51     567593   22601276
xvdap1            0.04         0.21         0.00        836          0
```

Any ideas for pushing up the performance?

```
Hardware (XEN guest)
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 30
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X3440  @ 2.53GHz
stepping        : 5
cpu MHz         : 2527.052
cache size      : 8192 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de tsc msr pae cx8 sep cmov pat clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good aperfmperf pni ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt hypervisor lahf_lm
bogomips        : 5054.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 30
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X3440  @ 2.53GHz
stepping        : 5
cpu MHz         : 2527.052
cache size      : 8192 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de tsc msr pae cx8 sep cmov pat clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good aperfmperf pni ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt hypervisor lahf_lm
bogomips        : 5054.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 2
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 30
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X3440  @ 2.53GHz
stepping        : 5
cpu MHz         : 2527.052
cache size      : 8192 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de tsc msr pae cx8 sep cmov pat clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good aperfmperf pni ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt hypervisor lahf_lm
bogomips        : 5054.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 3
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 30
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X3440  @ 2.53GHz
stepping        : 5
cpu MHz         : 2527.052
cache size      : 8192 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de tsc msr pae cx8 sep cmov pat clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good aperfmperf pni ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt hypervisor lahf_lm
bogomips        : 5054.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 4
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 30
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X3440  @ 2.53GHz
stepping        : 5
cpu MHz         : 2527.052
cache size      : 8192 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de tsc msr pae cx8 sep cmov pat clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good aperfmperf pni ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt hypervisor lahf_lm
bogomips        : 5054.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 5
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 30
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X3440  @ 2.53GHz
stepping        : 5
cpu MHz         : 2527.052
cache size      : 8192 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de tsc msr pae cx8 sep cmov pat clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good aperfmperf pni ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt hypervisor lahf_lm
bogomips        : 5054.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 6
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 30
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X3440  @ 2.53GHz
stepping        : 5
cpu MHz         : 2527.052
cache size      : 8192 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de tsc msr pae cx8 sep cmov pat clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good aperfmperf pni ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt hypervisor lahf_lm
bogomips        : 5054.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Meminfo

```
MemTotal:        6146908 kB
MemFree:         2231936 kB
Buffers:           45436 kB
Cached:          2542340 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          2629024 kB
Inactive:         915652 kB
Active(anon):     956724 kB
Inactive(anon):    46272 kB
Active(file):    1672300 kB
Inactive(file):   869380 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       2097144 kB
SwapFree:        2097144 kB
Dirty:            972812 kB
Writeback:          1412 kB
AnonPages:        956912 kB
Mapped:            18048 kB
Shmem:             46104 kB
Slab:             144676 kB
SReclaimable:     137764 kB
SUnreclaim:         6912 kB
KernelStack:        1136 kB
PageTables:         7524 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     5170596 kB
Committed_AS:    4964188 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       26032 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359711292 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     6156288 kB
DirectMap2M:           0 kB
```

An example schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Produkte` (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    uniqueID varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL, 
    Link varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL, 
    Title varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL, 
    foundTime varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL, 
    Desc text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL, 
    Rank int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10000000', 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE KEY uniqueID (uniqueID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC AUTO_INCREMENT=9407809 ;
```

Comment: Under Linux, high load an low CPU is usually the sign of disk contention.

Comment: How big is your `posts` table, and is your whole DB larger than your buffer pool size of 4G? It could just be that you're reading a lot from a large table that hasn't been cached and should change your query so it targets rows or a range or rows, rather than reads a whole table.

Comment: This question is un-answerable without more knowledge of the database table schemas involved. (e.g.: Perhaps the select is slow because there's no index, etc.)

Comment: this is my db stuktur: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uniqueID` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `Link` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `foundTime` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `Desc` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `Rank` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10000000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniqueID` (`uniqueID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC AUTO_INCREMENT=9407809 ;`

Comment: It looks like you've got over 9 million rows of possibly a KB each (although likely much less than that). If you run `SELECT * FROM posts;` on that data, you're pulling a maximum of more than 9GB back from the table in one query. That's always going to be slow if it's not in your buffer pool, and with only 4GB in your buffer pool that's not going to happen. I suggest you redesign the application so you don't read all posts at the same time.

Comment: Including the `text` column, that rises to a maximum of over 500GB from that query. You should really reconsider running statements like `select * from posts;`

Comment: Run a explain you are trying to return 9407808 (saw your AUTO_INCREMENT value) rows  disk based temporary must be created to handle your result set. The problem isn't the innodb engine but your query method